# Can't get my <li> image link to go to the href url

Tags: image, hyperlink

This is where the problems for me keeps existing.
Can't seem to figure out what i am doing wrong.

```
<div class="Flagholder">
<ul class="LangENG" style="position: relative; left: 10%;">
<li style="width: 250px; height: 50px;">
<a href="file://localhost/Users/Andreas/Desktop/Multimedia%20Design/Storcenterapp/en/eng.html" target="_self">
<img src="images/LangENG.png" alt="English" width="50px"></a></li></ul></div>
```

The CSS as it looks.

```
.Flagholder {
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
left: -5%;
top: 50%;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.LangENG {
overflow:hidden;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;

}

.LangENG a {
height:50px;
width:50px;
display: inline-block;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do specifically?

Comment: I would like the image to take me to another page.

Comment: Have you seen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Things_to_consider ?

Comment: Is *localhost* a PC a network location? If it is a local resource, triple forward slash must be used before "file" keyword instead.